# 20.04 sudo apt update is showing the error: http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-security Release 404 Not Found

Tags: apt, 20.04, security, update-manager, software-sources

I was trying the steps in following link:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe?action=show&redirect=KernelTeam%2FCrashdumpRecipe

FYI: the commands I used:
sudo apt-get install linux-crashdump

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys ECDCAD72428D7C01
sudo apt-get update
Sudo apt update is showing following result:

```
Err:15 http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.188.12 80]

Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C8CAB6595FDFF622
E: The repository 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-updates Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C8CAB6595FDFF622
E: The repository 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-updates Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-proposed Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C8CAB6595FDFF622
E: The repository 'ddebs ubuntu com focal-proposed Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: There is no -security available via that link; opening it with a browser will quickly show that... http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dists/   that wiki page is a little old & maybe needs an update.. *alas I'm not familiar with it enough myself to correct for later releases*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the below command:

```
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list << EOF
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ $(lsb_release -cs)          main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ $(lsb_release -cs)-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ $(lsb_release -cs)-updates  main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ $(lsb_release -cs)-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
EOF
```

After that delete the `/etc/apt/source.list.d/ddebs.list` file:

Then try running:

```
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a configuration option in order to update that repository. This error message is being displayed because the release file for the repository is either unsigned or it doesn't have a release file.

To set the output to display warnings instead of errors, you need to alter your `sources.list` file, which you have likely accessed recently, if you are seeing this message, and add the following flag to the entry that is showing as restricted:

```
allow-insecure=yes
```

This can be done also on a global level, but I wouldn't recommend it. If you keep it "per-repository",

**1.)** you will be able to see at any given point, which repositorie(s) is (are) unsigned by referring to your `sources.list`, and...

**2.)** you will know right away if, in the future, another repository that has been added is unsigned.

After it is enabled, it will still give a warning message, and apps downloaded will need to be confirmed as well.

This is all done to ensure that the files you recieve are what you are expecting, as they are coming from a relatively trustworthy source (or at the very least, one with something to lose.)

For more info on the topic, see the manual page for `apt-secure`

```
man apt-secure
```

Comment: Adding more detail. Give me a minute.